# How to display product with two condition, category and brand taxonomy

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I made a simple loop to display product base from category and brand (custom taxonomy.)

Here piece of my loop:

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 4, 
    'orderby'      => 'DESC',   

   'tax_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'brands',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms' => array($category)
       ),
         array( 
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'     => 'id',
            'terms' => array($category)
    )
),  

    );
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>
```

But nothing to display. 
When I change

```
        'relation' => 'AND', to 'relation' => 'OR',
```

The products displayed but only by brand.

**Practice with the following Nitin Singh Chouhan'S code and Champeau's suggestion, but still failed**

```
 <?php 
 $args = array(
'post_type' => array('post','product'),
'tax_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',
   array(
     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
     'terms' => array($category),
     'field' => 'id'
   ),
   array(
     'taxonomy' => 'brands',
     'terms' => array($categories_brands),
     'field' => 'id'
      ),
   )
 ); 

     );
     $wp_query = null;
     $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );?>

            <?php if ( $wp_query -> have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while ( $wp_query -> have_posts()) : $wp_query -> the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title(); ?>

        <?php 
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();
        endif;
        ?>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank for any kind of helps.

Comment: You are passing `array($category)` in both taxonomies!

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would print_r($category) and make sure it is giving you ID's and not slugs.  Also, you are submitting $category to both product_cat and brands.

If your field type were slug instead of id, and terms were exactly the same in both product_cat and brands then this would work... though it doesn't make sense in the grand scheme of things.

Your ID's are going to be unique from each taxonomy so passing $category to both taxonomies will not work.

I hope this helped.

Comment: Please check on my edited question above, I follow your suggestion. But still failed. Am I missing something? Thank you. @Champeau

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get product filter by category and brand (both) so you can add following code..

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post','product'),
    'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
         'terms' => 82,
         'field' => 'id'
       ),
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'brand',
         'terms' => 81,
         'field' => 'id'
       ),
    )
);
query_posts($args);

   if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();         
        the_title();        
    } 
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: @Nitin Singh Chouhan I am following your code, but the item did not display. Am I missing something? Please check on my edited question above. Thank you.